# Need to delete rows with NaN from dataframe - but only if there are other rows in the group that don't contain NaN

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset with millions of rows so I'd prefer to not brute-force with a loop. The problem can be modeled as follows:

```
data = {'A': ['I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'S'],
'B': ['J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J'],
'C': ['K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
'D': ['L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'T'],
'E': [np.nan, 'O', 'O', np.nan, 'Q', 'Q', np.nan],
'F': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
'G': ['N', 'N', 'N', np.nan, 'N', 'N', 'N'],
'H': [np.nan, np.nan, 'P', np.nan, np.nan, 'R', np.nan]}
```

whereas the result I'm looking for is:

```
   A  B  C  D    E  F  G     H
0  I  J  K  L    O  M  N     P
1  I  J  K  L    Q  M  N     R
2  S  J  K  T  NaN  M  N  None
```

If I group by the keys and rollup the data based on the last entry, I get:

`result_df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], as_index=False, dropna = False).last()`

```
   A  B  C  D     E  F  G     H
0  I  J  K  L     Q  M  N     R
1  S  J  K  T  None  M  N  None
```

I thought last() was supposed to only replace the NaN rows, but I lost the row with df['E'] == 'O'.

So I pull the column E in:

`result_df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], as_index=False, dropna = False).last()`

```
   A  B  C  D    E  F  G     H
0  I  J  K  L    O  M  N     P
1  I  J  K  L    Q  M  N     R
2  I  J  K  L  NaN  M  N  None
3  S  J  K  T  NaN  M  N  None
```

And it doesn't nuke the row where df['E'] == NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) after sorting the values (with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)), then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the original DataFrame. This enables you to identify the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) rows irrespective of the NaNs:

```
group = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

tmp = (df
       .sort_values(by=list(df))
       .groupby(group, as_index=False)
       .ffill()
       .join(df[group])
      )  

out = df[~tmp.duplicated().reindex(df.index)]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D    E  F  G    H
2  I  J  K  L    O  M  N    P
5  I  J  K  L    Q  M  N    R
6  S  J  K  T  NaN  M  N  NaN
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
     E  F  G    H  A  B  C  D
2    O  M  N    P  I  J  K  L
1    O  M  N    P  I  J  K  L
5    Q  M  N    R  I  J  K  L
4    Q  M  N    R  I  J  K  L
0    Q  M  N    R  I  J  K  L
3    Q  M  N    R  I  J  K  L
6  NaN  M  N  NaN  S  J  K  T
```

Comment: BRILLIANT!   I have some research to do on duplicated() to learn. Thanks!!!